# Pass array to an excel single cell from Python using xlwings

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, xlwings

Is it possible to pass an array from python using xlwings into a single cell in excel? When I attempt to pass a numpy array as a Range.value excel creates a horizontal range with each value in its own row. My code is similar to this:

```
import xlwings as xw
import numpy as np

xlist = list()
xlist.append(1)
xlist.append(2)

wb = xw.Workbook('xlwingstest.xlsx')

xw.Range("sheet1", "a1", asarray= True).value = np.asarray(list)
```

I am trying to avoid using VBA, but suspect I may not have a choice.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you want to have happen? What does it even mean for one cell to hold an array?

Comment: John - Thank you for taking the time to read my question. In the past I have used an array function with the bloomberg excel add-in, which allowed me apply an excel function to a set of data from bloomberg without storing the whole data set somewhere on that excel spreadsheet. I assumed that excel was storing that data set in a single cell, but thinking something else was going on.